# Entity Framework join tables

Tags: c#

I have the employee table in MVC project , when I run table Nationality , Gender ,and Department
It appears as a number, and I want to link the tables together so that names appear instead of numbers, how do I do that?

- by using C#

I tried to do the link using

```
  public ActionResult IndexEmp()
        {
            EmDBEntities1 db = new EmDBEntities1();
           var result = (from GenderID in db.Employees
                         join GenderName in db.Genders)
```

but I think my encoding is wrong .

Comment: I don't think the source code provided is compilable. Would be great if you can provide a minimal source code, the expected result, and the actual result. to reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Comment: If you have configured your mappings, it would be `Employees.Include(e => e.Gender)` if not you can use something like `from employee in db.Employees join gender in db.Genders on employee.GenderID equals gender.ID`

Comment: I suggest to have a look at some tutorials on Entity Framework. https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ is good place to start.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can please show your sample table data from both tables that you wants to join.